# How to get the logged in user details SSO Login in an ASP.NET MVC application with Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, single-sign-on

How to get the logged in user details in ASP.NET MVC using C# code with SSO Login authenticated in Azure AD. SSO Setup is done in Swagger. Can I get an example with code implementation?

I would like to know how I can retrieve the details from the app auth header

Comment: What is the version of your app?

Comment: Could you please your code of swagger.

Comment: There's a lot of documentation about this. Here's one possible place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory

Comment: I need to code of c#

Comment: @siri - Have you tried the code provided by Mark Seemann

Comment: My issue is solved. Thank you everyone.